# C# A ButtonClick action to replace all others?

Tags: c#, event-handling, action, buttonclick

I was wondering how I could set an EventHandler for a button click so that it would replace all other handlers for this objets. Ideally it would be something of the likes of:

```
button1.Click = MessageBox.Show("Run just this!"); //Yes, the '=' instead of the '+='.
```

This is because button1 already has a few click events, and I want to, in the determinated situation, overwrite all the other ones.

More examples:

```
button1.Click += MessageBox.Show("Event #1 has been triggered!");
button1.Click += MessageBox.Show("Event #2 and #1 have been triggered!");
button1.Click = MessageBox.Show("Event #3, and only #3, has been triggered!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this...

there is a  solution on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/576f69e7-55aa-4574-8d31-417422954689/). The sample code below will remove all `Click` events from `button1`.

you can keep one event on button .....

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Click += button1_Click;
            button1.Click += button1_Click2;
            button2.Click += button2_Click;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }

        private void button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("World");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveClickEvent(button1);
        }

        private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b)
        {
            FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", 
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
            PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",  
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
            list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first GetValue (on the static key) be passing null?

Comment: This will work, but violates a lot of design principles. I advise the OP not to use this approach, but instead to rethink how they subscribe. In particular: ***things you don't know about*** could be unsubscribe doing this.

Comment: I know this is rather not recommended, but it is an inovative code-only design for the application, which already has 8k lines of codes, so any other solution would probably cause months of maintenance. we're just trying to go another way, here!

Answer (score 0):

By design, you can't normally unsubscribe other callers. This is because they *aren't your concern*. You could use reflection to hack around it, but it is almost certainly an EventHandlerList so non-trivial. If you are us classing the control you could override OnClick to do this, but it still seems... antisocial.

If you are the one subscribing all these, you can simply ... not subscribe the things you don't want to run.